# unexpected output in function calls

Tags: c++, c

i have a program in which i have implemented main function as below and finally i getting a unexpected value of i.

```
 int main()
    {
        int fun (int);
        int i=3;
        fun(i=fun(fun(i)));
        printf("%d",i);
        return 0;
    }
```

and my function implementation is

```
int fun(int i)
{
    i++;
    return(i);

}
```

my output is:

```
5
```

what i expected was:

```
6
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be 6?

Comment: @awoodland: Why did you remove the C++ tag?

Comment: @david - There's nothing C++ about it and it's using `printf` which is decidedly C

Comment: @awoodland: While it is not *idimatic* C++, that code with the appropriate includes will compile in any C++ compiler. I think it is better to ask the person (@teacher in this case) to decide on what is the actual language of the question, noting that if it is C++ he will probably get also comments on how to make it more idiomatic

Comment: @David - agreed. My concern was that the answers *would* be notably different depending on which of C or C++ this was and I (inappropriately) took an educated guess on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
i = fun(i=fun(fun(i)));
```

This would give you 6

```
fun(i=fun(fun(i)));
```

This gives 5 because the last call does not assign the value to i.

Also as mentioned by Tom below i is being passed by value not reference, if you did pass by reference then it would be 6 if you did `fun(fun(fun(&i)));`(depending on what parameter type the function takes/returns).

Comment: and because i is being passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the argument by value, and returning that value. The variable `i` is only modified during initialization (set to 3) and in the call to the outer `fun` where it takes the value 5 returned from `fun(fun(3))`

**EDIT** C++ only (before @awoodland removed that tag from the question):

If you want to modify the external variable in the function you can do so by using references:

```
int& fun( int & x ) {
  return ++x;
}
int main() {
   int i = 3;
   fun( fun( fun( i ) ) );
// fun( i = fun( fun( i ) ) ); // alternatively
}
```

Comment: Fair point about the [tag:C++] tag, but doesn't that make the C tag inappropriate then?

Comment: @awoodland: The issue is that I don't know which of the two languages is the one that the teacher is interested in, and the decision of removing one or the other is arbitrary. The answer, on the other hand, is explicitly tackling one language C++, but that does not mean that teacher is interested in C++, only that *if* it is C++, this would be another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 3;

fun(i=fun(fun(i)));
        +
        |
        V
fun(i=fun(fun(3)));
        +
        |
        V
fun(i=fun(4));       /* fun (3) returns 4 */
        +
        |
        V
   fun(i=5);         /* fun (4) returns 5 and it is stored in i */
        +
        |
        V
    fun(5);         /* fun (5) returns 6, but it is NOWHERE stored, i is still 5 */

print i results in 5 .
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expectation comes from the `i++` being convention for `i = i + 1` and while that is true your issue here is scope. When you call a function in C like this add:

```
int add( int a, int b ) {
     a = a + b;
     return a;
}
```

you are passing by value. Which is to say that C is generating a duplicate of the values, thus you have a difference scope and thus things that happen inside of `add` only affect the things inside of add.

The other method you can pass data around in C is by reference like this

```
int * add( int * a, int b ) {
   (*a) = (*a) + b;
   return a;
}
```

that function will mutate the memory pointed to by `a*` and thus is "violating" it's scope. Using pass by reference you could have your function act in the manner you expected.